# Cannot create file in jenkins groovy pipeline (cat EOF)

Tags: file, jenkins, groovy, eof, cat

I want to create file with content in jenkins groovy pipeline (RHEL Slave).

Now I using this command

```
            steps {
                script {
                    sh """
                            cat <<EOF >>file.sh
                             echo 'Hello world'
                            EOF
                    """
                }    
            }
        }
```

But i got this message while run jenkins job.

```
2022-09-27 21:21:06  /apps/jenkins/workspace/xxxx/xxxxxx@tmp/durable-aa115c9c/script.sh: line 7: warning: here-document at line 2 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
2022-09-27 21:21:06  + cat
```

I already checked about space at EOF but still not work.

Please help suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it easy to do something like below? Simply redirecting the STDOUT to a file.

```
sh """
     echo 'Hello world' >> file.sh
     echo 'Hello Something' >> file.sh
"""
```